# Node.js process in async function blocks thread?

Tags: node.js, typescript, async-await

I am not sure if this is expected behaviour or not.

in Server.ts I handle a POST request that requires heavy calculation:

```js
app.post("/get-topics", async (req: Request, res: Response)=>{

    const posts = await pool.query(`<my sql search string here>`, [req.body.user]);
    const postText: string[] = posts.rows.map(p => p.content);

    const results = lda(postText, 5, 3); //takes 1 minute to finish executing
    res.json({'topics':results})

})
```

The function `lda` takes a minute to finish executing. When this is happening, basically the server is blocked. No HTTP requests can be made. I find this strange as it is in an async function so I would assume all the other `app.get` and `app.post` events would happen?

My question is, how can I get the server to handle other http requests while lda is executing? Or is this not possible in Node.js?

Edit: for context I am using Express, and the `lda` function is a node module (https://github.com/primaryobjects/lda/blob/master/lib/lda.js) which runs a statistical analysis on an array of strings.

Comment: Are you using express?

Comment: Make `lda` asynchronous. We can't help more with that since you're not showing what it's doing.

Comment: Your question is totally unrelated to `async/await`. And yes, NodeJS is single-threaded by default, but mind there's no relationship between `async/await` and threads. You can reference [this guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-multithreading-in-node-js#optimizing-a-cpu-intensive-task-using-four-worker-threads) to exploit several threads

Comment: @AlexanderSantos yes

Comment: "Takes more than a minute to finish" means it is actually using cpu and other resources or is it accessing database or any other I/O operation?

Comment: @AKX I am using an lda node module, https://github.com/primaryobjects/lda/blob/master/lib/lda.js , I suppose I can extend it, but I figured since it was wrapped in an async function that it would not block a thread?

Comment: @AlexanderSantos it is using the cpu and not waiting on database/io operations, it's running a statistical analysis on a lot of data held in memory

Comment: "I figured since it was wrapped in an async function that it would not block a thread?" that's only true for things that are *I/O bound*, not things that are *CPU bound*. There's only one thread, and if a flow of control does not yield execution then it ties up the thread. Running `(async () => { while (1) {}})();` will still cause your process to hang even though it's async because the while loop never stops.

Comment: @JaredSmith hmm so I am understanding that I should probably spawn a thread for this instead of using async/await?

Comment: @NullSalad correct....as far as it goes. I question whether or not that package is intended to be used in real time during an HTTP request/response cycle....

Comment: @NullSalad something similar to this. I highly recommend reading Digital Ocean's article posted by Christian, it may help with your questions

Comment: ok I'll look into using multithreading instead of async/await, thanks :) 
This package is probably not intended to be used in real time, but for my use case I will not have to handle very heavy traffic so it is mostly fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nodejs is an event-driven system that runs your javascript in a single thread.  It uses threads internally in its implementation, but other than a child process or a WorkerThread, it runs your javascript in just a single thread.  It works for responsive servers because most of what servers are doing is I/O to the file system, network or databases and nodejs has non-blocking, asynchronous  APIs for those types of operations which allow nodejs to do other things while those APIs are doing their work.  This works for most types of http servers and many other types of servers.

If this line of code:

```
const results = lda(postText, 5, 3);
```

takes a minute to process synchronously, then it will block nodejs from running any of your Javascript for that minute.  That's how nodejs works.  It's an event-driven system that runs your Javascript in a single thread.  So, it can't service the next event until the prior one returns control back to the system.

The fact that it's running inside an `async` function doesn't change any of that.  `async` just enables the use of `await` for awaiting a promise and converts exceptions into a rejected promise.  It doesn't magically make blocking, synchronous code into asynchronous code.

> My question is, how can I get the server to handle other http requests while lda is executing? Or is this not possible in Node.js?

First off, don't do any long running synchronous code in the main Javascript thread.  It doesn't appear that the lda code is designed to run in a nodejs server in the way you are using it because it appears to be long-running, synchronous, blocking code.

Second, if you absolutely have to run long running, blocking and synchronous code, then you have to move it out of the main Javascript thread, either to a child process or to a WorkerThread.  Nodejs programs that have to do heavy encoding or encrypting or image analysis or such will typically create some sort of thread pool so that work can be passed off to another thread and then the main thread is free to service other events from the event queue (e.g. process other connections).